# Webapp on Tomcat not responding

Tags: windows, rest, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a installed Tomcat7 on my Windows Server. And I have a war-file to deploy Java application with REST to my Tomcat. I have no problems to go to Application Manager and to deploy my app. But I have a problem to get response from that app. Previously it was install on another Tomcat server and it worked fine. I looked inside logs and found only this

```
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:42 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:45 +0200] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:46 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:40:50 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2538
10.10.1.32 - sa [23/Feb/2016:12:40:55 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 14084
10.10.1.32 - sa [23/Feb/2016:12:40:55 +0200] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2066
10.10.1.32 - sa [23/Feb/2016:12:40:55 +0200] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7279
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:12:42:12 +0200] "GET /uniteh-bau/rest/settings/setServerName/tsrv HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:20 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:25 +0200] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:13:01:48 +0200] "GET /uniteh-bau/rest/settings/info HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:14:06:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:14:08:41 +0200] "GET /uniteh-bau/rest/settings/setServerName/tsrv HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:14:55:20 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
10.10.1.32 - - [23/Feb/2016:14:55:30 +0200] "GET /uniteh-bau/rest/settings/setServerName/tsrv HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I use internet browser to test my app. But the only thing I can see is a blank page. In the logs all my requests are marked with 404 in the end of log. Did I something miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those path's are all relative to the root (`/`) of your server. Tomcat doesn't work like that - you can see those three requests to `/manager/` result in status `200`.

Likewise, your .war is installed as a webapp under a certain name and all requests need to be relative to that webapp's name:

[image]

in that case, all requests must go to `https://myserver.com:port/myWar/*`

The issue could be caused if you used an apache httpd in front of the Tomcat which rewrote URLs and your links/bookmarks still point to the root-relative paths.

**TL;DR:** just go to the manager app and click on the link to your application.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you tell me please, can apache httpd be switched off? I've found [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html)

Comment: Sure, `apachectl stop` or `apache2ctl stop`. But that should not be your current problem.

Comment: I've reinstall Tomcat at all, switched off httpd and deployed my web app again and now it works as I want. Thank you.